# inPHP time returns wrong timestamp

Tags: php, time, timestamp

PHP script adds user messages to the database, using `time()` to get server time. It worked fine for several years, but now `time()` returns different timestamps for different users:

```
[01:30] User1: Hi!
[01:27] User2: Hello!
[01:30] User1: How are you?
[01:27] User2: Fine.
```

Script:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// ...

$now = time();

// add message to database
```

How is it possible?
As far as I know, function `time()` returns always timestamp that is timezone independent.
Script works on godaddy shared hosting.

Comment: maybe you need to specify: `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam'); //Change Europe/Amsterdam to something else` and check out: http://nl3.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php all the different types are there

Comment: How does it affect on `time()`?

Comment: Offcourse, timezone doesn't affect on `time()` result. But how you output/format time such as `[01:30]`?

Comment: From the little bit of code given it's impossible to reason about any problems. The code you show and the output are also completely disconnected, it's unclear how you get from one to the other.

Comment: hindmost, `echo date('H:i:d', $timestamp_added);` It's not a problem of output, because there are other scripts that operate with timestamps, check their differencies, and that's how I found this time sync problem.

Answer (score 4):

It seems likely that your shared hosting is on some kind of cluster (just like ours </shameless-selfpromotion>)

This is great for performance, but it's unfortunately common for low-end shared hosting providers to not care enough about their servers.

In particular, in this case, the clocks of the servers your hosting is on are out of sync. One server seems to be a few minutes slow, causing the result you see.

Your options are:

- Contact your host and ask them to fix it (good luck with GoDaddy on that...)
- Switch to better hosting (shameless self-promotion intensifies - see my Profile page if interested :p)
- Switch to a dedicated server.

<sub><sub><sub>Hey, we even migrate your site for you, for free!</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: Thank you for the tip. You are right, GoDaddy support sucks.